# JpaRepository insert doesn't work [Spring Boot + MySQL]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

First of all, I have to state that I have 3 databases enabled in my project.

Any method about insertion to the database doesn't seem to apply, but the select methods do. That's the weird thing, it isn't that Spring Boot cannot determine which database to use because the same repository selects from the correct database  but cannot insert. In addition, I get no errors, in Java environment neither in MySQL ( I enabled debug options on `application.properties` )

To summarize, `save` method doesn't insert to the database but the same repository selects without any issues. I checked if I have privileges for insertion into the database and I do (I also added them again just in case).
I am using the same entity for both selection and insertion. 
The table I want to access is named `log` and the database `db1`. In addition, insertion works on `db3`.

Also, I have configured `DataSource` for all three databases.
I would like to add, that there are multiple tables on the three databases that have the same name. For other reasons, I can't give you the exact naming, but I would try of course any suggestions about naming. But I have to say, on all three databases the selection happens exactly as wanted.

`application.properties`

```
server.port=8086

db1.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db1.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1

db2.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db2.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1

db3.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db3.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

jwt.header=Authorization
jwt.secret= //mysecret
jwt.expiration=14400
jwt.route.authentication.path=/login
jwt.route.authentication.refresh=/refresh

spring.profiles.active=prod

webapp.cors.allowedOrigins= //list of allowed origins


spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

`application-prod.properties`

```
server.port=8086

db1.datasource.url= //db1 url
db1.datasource.username= //username
db1.datasource.password= //password
db1.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db1.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db1.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1

db2.datasource.url= //db2 url
db2.datasource.username= //username
db2.datasource.password= //password
db2.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db2.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db2.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1

db3.datasource.url= //db3 url
db3.datasource.username= //username
db3.datasource.password= //password
db3.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db3.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
db3.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

`Log` JPA entity , `log` is the name of the table in database `db1`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log" , catalog = "db1")
public class Log implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long logID;
    private Integer uploadSeq;
    private String date;

    public Log() {
    }

    public Log(Integer uploadSeq, String date) {
        this.uploadSeq = uploadSeq;
        this.date = date;
    }


    @Column(name = "logID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getLogID() {
        return logID;
    }


    public void setLogID(Long logID) {
        this.logID = logID;
    }


    @Column(name = "uploadSeq", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUploadSeq() {
        return uploadSeq;
    }


    public void UploadSeq(Integer uploadSeq) {
        this.uploadSeq = uploadSeq;
    }


    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }


    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

`Db1LogRepository` repository for `log` table

```
public interface Db1LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log,Long> {


    public Log findFirstByOrderByLogIDDesc(); //is being used on another part of the project

}
```

`Db1LogComponent` component for accessing the repository

```
@Component
public class Db1LogComponent {

    @Autowired
    Db1logRepository db1LogRepository;


    public void addDate(Log log) {

        System.out.println(db1LogRepository.findAll().size()); //Retrieves the correct entities of the table log in db1
        db1LogRepository.save(log); //Doesn't save to the database
    }

}
```

**Edit:** DB3 has `@Primary` annotation on config file, where the other two configs about the other two databases don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are using @Repository
@Transactional annotations on top of repository like below.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface Db1LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log,Long>
```

Comment: I've tried with plenty of annotations I must say and your suggestion doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: I needed to add `@Transactional("db1TransactionManager")`. I marked your answer as the correct one, because it guided me to search more about `@Transactional`

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: In which class did you add this, and can you share the definition of "db1TransactionManager", I have the same problem and couldn't solve it